# Can I reference a substring of a string function result?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a function `str` that takes an integer and converts it to a string.  I also want to consider a substring of the string of that value, which would be easy if it were a character value rather than a character function.

In other words, I'd like to write something like this:

```
str(12345)(2:3)
```

instead of having to do this:

```
character(10) :: c
c = str(12345)
print *, c(2:3)
```

or rolling my own `substr()` function.  Is there any way to do what I want without storing the character value in a temporary character variable or writing another function?

Here's a complete program:

```
program main

   character(10) :: c

   ! works fine
   c = str(12345)
   print *, c(2:3)

   ! nope
   print *, str(12345)(2:3)

   ! this would work if i wrote a substr function
   print *, substr( str(12345), 2, 3 )

contains

   character(len=1064) function str(k)
      ! convert an integer to string
      integer, intent(in) :: k
      write (str, *) k
      str = adjustl(str)
   end function str

end program main
```

Comment: @francescalus  I don't know if it's the same or not but Vladimir's answer is essentially the same so I'm happy to accept the expertise of you and Vladimir at this point, but I'll still be interested in any helpful ideas

Comment: How about adding an optional argument to str(), e.g., str( 12345, idx=[2,3] )?

Comment: Yeah, it is very similar to arrays. I did actually try to search for a duplicate, but didn't see that one among the first hits.

Comment: @roygvib  Thanks, I think that's a good idea and similar in spirit to writing an additional `substr` function which is most likely what I'll do (just b/c other languages have `substr` so it will be user friendly in that sense).  The fortran folks are super quick to close questions here, it would be nice if they could be left open for partial solutions as I'm kinda looking for a variety of options here.

Comment: I would actually encourage @roygvib to add (suitably phrased) that comment as an answer to the other question.  If one has the freedom to modify the function then that's a perfectly viable approach in both cases (array sections and substrings having much in common), subject to design considerations.

Comment: @francescalus I have just read the other question and tried to write some user-defined counterpart of shape() that has an optional argument (e.g., getshape( A ) and getshape( A, idx=1 ) ), but they need to return an array and a scalar, respectively, so I got stuck there... If the return value is a character string, this problem does not happen because I just need to substring and trim the result.

Comment: @roygvib, agreed.  A character substring is a scalar just as much as the string is, differing from an array element and an array.  However, rather than an optional argument `idx` you could make it non-optional and have two specific functions, one returning an array and one a scalar ("array element"), under the same generic.

Comment: I'm kind of bummed because this is not a duplicate of the referenced question and in fact this one has an answer, but I can't post it here and it's not relevant to the other question because there seems to be a problem in that case where the type of an array element has allocatable components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot substring or array-index a Fortran expression. And a function result is an expression. The closest thing to avoiding a temporary is using `associate` from Fortran 2003, but you won't save much code either

```
associate(c=>str(12345))
  print *,c(2:3)
end associate
```